# Inserir caractere em uma posição específica

Tags: php

**Problema**

Como inserir um caractere em posição específica?

**Exemplo**

No meu caso no 4º caractere

```
str = 30000000
gostaria que ela ficasse assim: 3000.0000
```

Comment: acho que o substr vai resolver seu problema então: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php  com ele dá pra separar a string e colocar o "." no meio

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### O PHP já tem função nativa para isto:

```
$resultado = substr_replace($original, '.', $posicao, 0);
```

### Parâmetros:

- *String* original
- Caracteres a serem inseridos na posição
- Posição (positiva contando do começo da string, negativa contando do fim da string)
- Quantidade de caracteres a remover naquela posição.

### Aplicando ao seu caso:

Se quiser contando 4 da esquerda:

```
$resultado = substr_replace($original, '.', 4, 0);
```

Se quiser contando 4 da direita:

```
$resultado = substr_replace($original, '.', -4, 0);
```

Veja ambos os casos funcionando no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/Z52Yjd)**.

Mais detalhes no manual:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr-replace.php

Comment: *Pra que reinventar a roda quando já existe pronto?* +1

Answer (score 13):

## Solução

- Criei uma função para ficar mais fácil de trabalhar e assim ela pode ser reaproveitada em outros lugares.
- Utilizo a função `substr` para pegar da opção "0" até a posição passada como parâmetro, no exemplo em questão até a posição "4", retornando então "3000".
- Novamente utilizando a função `substr` para pegar o final da `string`, apenas informando a quantidade, no caso "4", me retornando os últimos 4 dígitos da `string` "0000".
- Para ficar um pouco mais dinâmica a função, coloquei um parâmetro o caractere que será inserido no meio da `string`, no exemplo em questão ".".
- E por fim concateno toda a string formando "3000.0000".

## Código

```
function insertInPosition($str, $pos, $c){
    return substr($str, 0, $pos) . $c . substr($str, $pos);
}

$str = "30000000";
echo insertInPosition($str, 4, '.');
```

**Saída**

```
3000.0000
```

[Executar](https://ideone.com/oCsIZw)

## Conclusão

É uma forma interessante para resolver o problema, contudo já existe um método do próprio PHP que soluciona este problema, e esta resposta foi dada pelo nosso amigo [Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/70/bacco) [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/296903/74441).

Comment: perfeito cara! muito obrigado