# Formatar casas decimais em PHP

Tags: php

Tenho um modulo de pagamento onde eu devo passar os dados sem casas decimais, somente número. Exemplos:

> `1000` = `10.00`
>
> `10030` = `100.30`
>
> `100000` = `1000.00`

Pesquisei sobre alguma função em `php` que ***formate casas decimais***, mas os teste que realizei não saíram como o esperado, alguém poderia me auxiliar nessa questão?

Comment: Me parece o mesmo problema desta: [Inserir caractere em uma posição específica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/296897/70) - Aplicado ao seu caso: `substr_replace($valor, '.', -2, 0)` - no caso, o problema não tem nada a ver com formatação de casa decimal, seus dados de origem não tem casas decimais de fato, e sim estão em outra escala. Ainda, se não for questão de exibição, basta `$valor/100` em vez de complicar. Se for questão de exibição, vai ter que manipular string de qq forma.

Comment: A [resposta do Heitor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/492314/112052) falha para valores menores que 10 (por exemplo, se for `1`, entendo que o resultado deveria ser `0.01`, mas a solução dele resulta em `.1`). Não sei se você vai ter casos assim, mas em todo caso fica o aviso :-) (e também deixei [uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/492324/112052) que funciona para esses casos)

Answer (score 5):

Para que `1000` (ou seja, "mil") se torne `10.00` (ou seja, "dez" formatado com 2 casas decimais), basta dividir o valor por 100 e usar a [função `number_format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php), com a qual você escolhe a quantidade de casas decimais a serem exibidas (no caso, `2`) e o caractere usado como separador decimal (no caso, o ponto):

```
function formatar($valor) {
    return number_format($valor / 100, 2, '.', '');
}

echo formatar(1000); // 10.00
echo formatar(10030); // 100.30
echo formatar(100000); // 1000.00
```

Já o quarto parâmetro é o separador de milhares, mas como parece que você não quer, basta passar a string vazia.

---

Com isso você pode facilmente customizar a quantidade de casas decimais:

```
function formatar($valor, $casas=2) {
    return number_format($valor / (10 ** $casas), $casas, '.', '');
}

echo formatar(100000); // 1000.00 
echo formatar(100000, 3); // 100.000
```

---

Eu acho bem mais simples do que ficar manipulando strings manualmente, pegando pedaços dela com `substr`, fazendo `replace`, etc. Tudo bem que `number_format` também deve manipular strings internamente, mas ainda acho melhor do que fazer tudo na mão.

Outra vantagem de usar uma solução matemática é que também funciona para valores menores que 100. Por exemplo, `formatar(1)` resulta na string `0.01` - já usando a solução da [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/492314/112052) (que foi apagada), o resultado será `.1` (que está errado, pois `.1` corresponde a `0.10`).

Comment: @HeitorScalabrini Se `1000` se torna `10.00`, então `1` deveria se tornar `0.01` (me parece o caso clássico de receber a quantidade de centavos e formatar como valor monetário - mesmo que não seja, a ideia é similar). E "manipular strings internamente" é porque `number_format` retorna uma string formatada, e para isso ela deve construir a string (colocar os caracteres certos nos lugares corretos, etc, ou seja, internamente, ela deve manipular a string para construir a formatação desejada)