# "echo" mostra número decimal com virgula em vez de ponto

Tags: php, php-7

Tenho este código no PHP 7:

```
$total_pedido = 123.90;
$frete_valor = 13.98;

$total_geral = ($total_pedido + $frete_valor);

echo ($total_geral); // Mostra 137,88
```

O resultado da soma (`137.88`) o que está correto, porém dando um `echo` (sem nenhum tratamento) ele traz `137,88` com virgula, não deveria vir com ponto?

Devido a esse resultado com virgula tenho que tratar a string antes de enviar a um webservice.

Esse comportamento é normal no PHP ou é devido a alguma configuração no `php.ini`?

Comment: Provavelmente é por causa do *locale*, mas eu não lembro de onde o PHP pega isso (se é do sistema operacional ou do php.ini). De qualquer forma, se quer controlar a forma como o número é formatado, independente da configuração do *locale*, use `number_format`: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/492324/112052

Comment: Creio que esteja enganado @hkotsubo, mas talvez eu esteja por fora, de qualquer forma desconheço tal comportamento em PHP, digo especificamente em uma operação matematica simples isso não deveria ocorrer, até aonde sei, o setlocale (ou default_locale no php.ini) afeta muitas coisas, mas não a saída do echo, em questão de numeros o que ele vai afetar é o `localeconv()`, tanto para LC_MONETARY quanto para LC_NUMERIC

Comment: Marcelo, pode imprimir o `print_r(localeconv());` no mesmo script e devolver os resultados ao [edit] a pergunta?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Fiz um teste aqui (PHP 7.4.3/Ubuntu 20) e se fizer `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.utf8')`, o `echo` mostra `137,88`. Se mudar para, por exemplo, `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf8')`, aí passa a mostrar `137.88`. Mas como eu já disse, não sei exatamente de onde o PHP pega essas configs, então pode ter sido coincidência ou alguma config específica da minha máquina, não sei. Em IDE's online não deu diferença, e meu palpite é que elas não tenham o locale pt_BR instalado, mas novamente, é só palpite meu...

Answer (score 2):

Conforme a [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting) até o PHP7.x a conversão de string era afetada pelo `locale`

Um valor pode ser convertido em uma string usando o `(string) $variavel` ou a função `strval()`. A conversão de string é feita automaticamente no escopo de uma expressão onde uma string é necessária. Isso acontece ao usar as funções de `echo` ou `print`, ou quando uma variável é comparada a uma `string`. As seções sobre [Types](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.php) e [Type Juggling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) tornarão o seguinte mais claro.

Um `int` ou `float` é convertido em uma string que representa o número textualmente (incluindo a parte do expoente para `floats`). Os números de ponto flutuante podem ser convertidos usando a notação exponencial (4.1E+6).

No PHP8, o caractere do ponto decimal é sempre o "ponto" (`.`). **Antes do PHP8**, o caractere do ponto decimal é definido no `locale` do script (`LC_NUMERIC`), que justamente é o ocorrido em seu caso.

Em resumo **antes do PHP8** era afetado pelo `locale`, para fazer o teste usei o `German_Germany.1252`:

```
<?php

setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'German_Germany.1252');

// Apenas obtem o locale atual, sem alterar
$locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, 0);

echo 10.14, "\n";

var_dump($locale);
```

No PHP7

```
10,14
string(99) "LC_COLLATE=C;LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252;LC_MONETARY=C;LC_NUMERIC=German_Germany.1252;LC_TIME=C"
```

Saída no PHP8:

```
10.14
string(78) "LC_COLLATE=C;LC_CTYPE=C;LC_MONETARY=C;LC_NUMERIC=German_Germany.1252;LC_TIME=C"
```

Possíveis causas da saída atual estar com vírgula:

- Você pode estar usando um [`auto_prepend_include`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) que esteja usando `setlocale()`
- O `LC_NUMERIC` (ou `LC_ALL`) pode ter sido configurado no `/etc/default/locale`
- Ou até mesmo pode ter sido uma configuração no `.bashrc`

Confira essas situações (o SetEnv do Apache eu não pude testar, talvez em Fast-CGI exista alguma configuração que afete o `locale`, se encontrar algum detalhe atualizo a resposta).

Comment: Apenas para constar, no php.ini o `intl.default_locale` é usado para as as funções Intl: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php, o que não é o caso da conversão para string.